# IOS Core Data:how to store the MutableArray object

Tags: ios, core-data, nsmanagedobject

I have an `NSManagedObject` class which has a field of type `NSMutableArray`, but when I call the `[self.managedObjectContext save:&error];` the `NSMutableArray` field doesn't save the change.

The other fields, like `NSString` save as expected.

How can I save the `NSMutableArray` into the Core Data store, or is there any alternative way to do this?

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>

@interface CatelogsList : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray* list;

@end

- (IBAction)addCatelog
{
   NSString* nextname=self.catelogText.text;
   Catelog* newCatelog=[[Catelog alloc] init];
   newCatelog.name=nextname;
   newCatelog.texts=[[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:20];
   [list addObject:newCatelog];

   //where list is the reference of the 'list' field in the NSManagedObject class above
   [self.managedObjectContext save:nil];
   NSLog(@"saved");
}
```

the list doesn't save any change, the size of the list come back to 0 whenever I restart the program

Comment: The first step would be to use the `error` parameter of the `save` method and check its return value.

Answer (score 1):

Don't just add your own property to the managed object class. Add the attribute into the model and set its type to `transformable`. By default this uses an archiver to write the array into the data store.

Properties you explicitly add to the managed object subclass are not backed by the data store and will never be saved.

Comment: I did it again exactly with the way that you said,but still not working

Comment: So you removed the property, updated the Core Data model, regenerated the managed object subclass, updated code to use the new property? Show that code in an edit to the question. Include the .h & .m for the managed object class and the code that calls it. What error does the save return?

Answer (score 0):

Build your data model first, and add the required attributes that way, and the save method will write them to the persistent store.

As I understand it, added properties that are not part of the managed object model will never be saved.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store a self-defined class into the SQLite database, you need to define the two methods for the custom class: `(void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder)coder;` and `-(id)decodeWithCoder:(NSCoder*)decoder;`